# Maven maven-jaxb2-plugin with NTLM Authentication

Tags: java, maven, soap, ntlm

I have a SOAP web service running on windows which is secured with NTLM authentication. I cannot change this. When I open an URL to the web service I get a password dialog and when I authenticate then I can see the WSDL, so I know it is working.

Now I am trying to configure Maven to generate Java classes from the WSDL. I found the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` for Maven and it should be suitable for this task. My problem now is that I am on Linux and I do not know how to give this plugin or maven the necessary credentials to connect to the web service.

So my question is is it possible to configure the above plugin such that I can pass it the NTLM credentials?

Here is the configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>com.example</generatePackage>
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>http://192.168.0.10:7047/path/To/WSDL</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Update: when I run the goal `mvn jaxb2:generate` on windows, then the generation works automatically without password. But this is not really a solution because I don't want to switch to windows each time I need to regenerate from the wsdl.

Comment: Hi @Ianoxx, are you solved it? I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Comment: Hi @IgnacioOcampo, I really almost forgot about this question. I have not really solved it, but I used a different solution in the end. I am now using the `jaxws-maven-plugin` and execute the `wsimport` goal. When ever there is a change in the web service I manually download the WSDL files on a windows box and copy them to the project folder. If you know how I can get Maven to access some URL (which is secured by NTLM) and then download all the WSDL files it finds there (and optionally also generate POJOs from it), then please add an answer to this question.

Comment: Hi @lanoxx, my service do it, it authenticate for you and return wsdl, so, you can use it with wsimport, are you interested in it?

Comment: Currently its not that urgent, but I will keep it in mind and have another look when its out of beta. Thanks anyways.